# Kotlin One type argument expected for class for abstract generic view holder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I'm trying to create a  RecyclerView.Adapter with the following:

---

### View holders - Provided the abstract parent and one son

```
abstract class BaseSettingsViewHolder<T>(var viewDataBinding : 
ViewDataBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewDataBinding.root) {

   abstract fun onBind(data: T, presenter: ISettingsPresenter, position: Int)
}
```

---

```
class SettingsTitleViewHolder(viewDataBinding: ViewDataBinding) : BaseSettingsViewHolder<TitleData>(viewDataBinding) {

    override fun onBind(data: TitleData, presenter: ISettingsPresenter, position: Int) {
        viewDataBinding.setVariable(BR.titleData, data)
        viewDataBinding.setVariable(BR.itemPosition, position)
        viewDataBinding.setVariable(BR.settingsPresenter, presenter)
        viewDataBinding.executePendingBindings()
    }

}
```

And when trying to declare the adapter:

```
class SettingsAdapter(var context: Context, var presenter: ISettingsPresenter) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseSettingsViewHolder>() {
```

I'm getting "One type argument expected for class" compile error on the:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseSettingsViewHolder>
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

1- If you use always **SettingTitleViewHolder**;

```
RecyclerView.Adapter<SettingTitleViewHolder>
```

2- If you want to use any class which extended **BaseSettingViewHolder**;

```
RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseSettingsViewHolder<*>>
```

3- Use **Any Object Type**

```
RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseSettingsViewHolder<Any>>
```

4- Use extended type parameter for adapter class

```
class SettingsMenuAdapter<T>:RecyclerView.Adapter<T> where T : BaseSettingViewHolder<*>
```

5- Define out for abstract class type parameter.

```
abstract class BaseSettingsViewHolder<out T> RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseSettingsViewHolder<Any>>
```

7- Read that article =>
["Generics in Kotlin"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) ;)

Comment: You must have TitleData extend from RecyclerView Adapter ViewHolder.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify the type argument for the `BaseSettingsViewHolder` in the `RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseSettingsViewHolder>` type.

Kotlin, unlike Java, does not have the raw types, so you cannot simply omit the type arguments.

The closest concept to raw types is [star-projected types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections): use `BaseSettingsViewHolder<*>` in `RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseSettingsViewHolder<*>>`, this will mean that the type argument for `BaseSettingsViewHolder` is unknown.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but I already tried and it gives me an  error while calling holder.onBind(dataList[position], presenter, position) in the onBindViewHolder. I'm getting Out-projected type 'BaseSettingsViewHolder<*>' prohibits the use of 'public abstract fun onBind(data: T, presenter: ISettingsPresenter, position: Int): Unit defined in BaseSettingsViewHolder'

Comment: Can you provide some concrete type, then? `RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseSettingsViewHolder<SomeType>>`