# Kotlin issue “One type argument expected for class ExpandableRecyclerAdapter”

Tags: java, android-studio, generics, kotlin, android-recyclerview

**Got problems with RecyclerAdapter ViewHolder**

```
abstract class ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<T : ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ListItem>(private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    protected var allItems = ArrayList<T>()

    ...

    open inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
    open class ListItem(val itemType: Int = 0)  
}
```

ExpandableRecyclerAdapter in `<...>` is underlined with error:

> One type argument expected for class ExpandableRecyclerAdapter< T : ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ListItem>

However, if I declare my ViewHolder class as static (by removing inner), the error disappears, but it is unacceptable for me.

Advices like here are not going to be helpful: [Kotlin One type argument expected for class for abstract generic view holder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051190/kotlin-one-type-argument-expected-for-class-for-abstract-generic-view-holder)

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kotlin does not allow generic types to be specified without providing generics unless you're referring to a non-instance member of the class. (static inner classes, `::class`, companion methods). Since `ViewHolder` is an inner class its identity depends on the exact specification of its outer class when talking about the type itself.

This means you cannot refer to a generic `ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder`, you must specify the bounds in which the outer class lies as well. Changing it to `ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<T>.ViewHolder` should solve the issue.